# How to setup CLion IDE with custom libc++ and clang?

Tags: clion, libc++

CLion website says they support "libc++" but there is no information on how to set up CLlion to use libc++. I'm using Ubuntu 16 and downloaded libc++ source and built it. So I want to use this specific version.

Here's what I've tried so far:

So I have now libc++ binaries. Then I created simple hello world project and changed its CMakeLists.txt to use my custom libc++. However when I try to run the project, I get error:

```
/home/shitals/CLionProjects/JsonTest/cmake-build-debug/JsonTest: error while loading shared libraries: libc++.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Here's my project cmake to force using my custom libc++.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(JsonTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

#libcxx which we will use with specific version of clang
SET(LIBCXX_INC_PATH /home/shitals/mylibc++/include/c++/v1)
SET(LIBCXX_LIB_PATH /home/shitals/mylibc++/lib)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER clang-3.9)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER clang++-3.9)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "\
                -std=c++14 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wstrict-aliasing -Wunreachable-code -Wcast-qual -Wctor-dtor-privacy \
                -Wdisabled-optimization -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wswitch-default \
                -Wold-style-cast -Woverloaded-virtual -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Wswitch-default -Wundef \
                -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-parentheses -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused -Wno-documentation -fdiagnostics-show-option -ferror-limit=10 \
                -pthread ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "\
                    -nostdinc++ -isystem ${LIBCXX_INC_PATH} \
                    -D__CLANG__ ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "\
                    ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -stdlib=libc++ -lc++ -lc++abi -lm -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc -ldl \
                    -L ${LIBCXX_LIB_PATH}")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(JsonTest ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

My compiled libc++ binaries does have libc++.so.1 file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... so below CMakeLists.txt in project root does seem to work:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(JsonTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

#libcxx which we will use with specific version of clang
SET(LIBCXX_INC_PATH /home/shitals/GitHubSrc/AirSim/llvm-build/output/include/c++/v1)
SET(LIBCXX_LIB_PATH /home/shitals/GitHubSrc/AirSim/llvm-build/output/lib)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER clang-3.9)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER clang++-3.9)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "\
                -std=c++14 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wstrict-aliasing -Wunreachable-code -Wcast-qual -Wctor-dtor-privacy \
                -Wdisabled-optimization -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wswitch-default \
                -Wold-style-cast -Woverloaded-virtual -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Wswitch-default -Wundef \
                -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-parentheses -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused -Wno-documentation -fdiagnostics-show-option -ferror-limit=10 \
                -pthread ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "\
                    -nostdinc++ -isystem ${LIBCXX_INC_PATH} \
                    -D__CLANG__ ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "\
                    ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -v -nodefaultlibs -lc++ -lc++abi -lm -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc -ldl \
                    -L ${LIBCXX_LIB_PATH}")

LINK_DIRECTORIES(${LIBCXX_LIB_PATH})

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(JsonTest ${SOURCE_FILES})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(JsonTest c++ c++abi)
```